# cout prints wrong data with ++ and -- operator

Tags: c++

one of my friends asked me a question about ++ and -- operators and printing an int with cout .
In his example he used kinda this code(I changed code in order to be readable):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int  a=5;
   cout<<a<<a++<a;
}
```

and the output was this:

```
656
```

Why is that and what causes this ?
It should print 556 .And also it happens with -- operator too

Comment: *"It should print 556"*. Should it? Where did you read the evaluation order of function parameters is specified like that?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_increment_decrement_operators.htm
this is a link but im looking into my books

Comment: c++ how to program 8th edition by deitel & deitel
chapter 4 fig.4.18

Comment: You didn't read there that `a` will be evaluated first, then `a++` and finally `a`. The evaluation order of function arguments (`operator<<` is a function here, applied multiple times) is undefined.

Comment: excuse me but what do you mean by "undefined"?

Comment: I mean the c++ standard explicitly says it's undefined. It doesn't impose an order, so 556 is just as valid as 656. And it's completely up to the implementation of your compiler.

Comment: But we call "<<function(operator)" inorder.Doesn't it make any differences?

Comment: @StoryTeller actually the evaluation order of operands is unspecified

Comment: @M.M Yes, I know the standard uses *undefined* and *unspecified* to mean to different things. But alas, my memory always fails me when it's time to be precise :)